# textarea autogrow functionality jitters with every keystroke

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was playing around with the jquery autogrow plugin, which expands the height of the text automatically as the text needs it. The problem is that with every key down, the bottom border of the textarea jitters in a noticeable way. I'm not sure what the problem could be, so I'm going to go out on a limb and post the 132 lines of this GPL plugin here. Any hints where the problem could be or how to circumvent it?

```
         /* 

      Auto Expanding Text Area (1.2.2)  by Chrys Bader */

        (function(jQuery) {
           var self = null;     
           jQuery.fn.autogrow = function(o){
             return this.each(function() {  
                new jQuery.autogrow(this, o);
             });
           };


      /**
      * The autogrow object.
      *
      * @constructor
      * @name jQuery.autogrow
      * @param Object e The textarea to create the autogrow for.
      * @param Hash o A set of key/value pairs to set as configuration properties.
      * @cat Plugins/autogrow
      */        

     jQuery.autogrow = function (e, o) {
        this.options = o || {};         
        this.dummy = null;
        this.interval = null;
        this.line_height = this.options.lineHeight || parseInt(jQuery(e).css('line-height'));
        this.min_height = this.options.minHeight || parseInt(jQuery(e).css('min-height'));
        this.max_height = this.options.maxHeight || parseInt(jQuery(e).css('max-height'));;
        this.textarea = jQuery(e);

       if(this.line_height == NaN) this.line_height = 0;

       // Only one textarea activated at a time, the one being used
       this.init();     
    };  

    jQuery.autogrow.fn = jQuery.autogrow.prototype = { autogrow: '1.2.2' };
    jQuery.autogrow.fn.extend = jQuery.autogrow.extend = jQuery.extend;
    jQuery.autogrow.fn.extend({ init: function(){
       var self = this;
       this.textarea.css({overflow: 'hidden', display: 'block'});
       this.textarea.bind('focus', function(){ self.startExpand() }).bind('blur', function() { self.stopExpand() });
       this.checkExpand();
    },

    startExpand: function() { 
        var self = this;
        this.interval = window.setInterval(function() { self.checkExpand()}, 400); },
    stopExpand: function() { clearInterval(this.interval); },
    checkExpand: function() { 
       if (this.dummy == null) {
          this.dummy = jQuery('<div></div>');
          this.dummy.css({
             'font-size'  : this.textarea.css('font-size'),
             'font-family': this.textarea.css('font-family'),
             'width'      : this.textarea.css('width'),
             'padding'    : this.textarea.css('padding'),
             'line-height': this.line_height + 'px',
             'overflow-x' : 'hidden',
             'position'   : 'absolute',
             'top'        : 0,
             'left'    : -9999
          }).appendTo('body');
      }
// Strip HTML tags          
var html = this.textarea.val().replace(/(<|>)/g,'');
// IE is different, as per usual            
if ($.browser.msie){
    html = html.replace(/\n/g, '<BR>new');
} else {
    html = html.replace(/\n/g, '<br>new');
}

if (this.dummy.html() != html){
   this.dummy.html(html);

if (this.max_height > 0 && (this.dummy.height() + this.line_height > this.max_height)){
    this.textarea.css('overflow-y', 'auto');
} else { 
    this.textarea.css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
    if (this.textarea.height() < this.dummy.height() + this.line_height || (this.dummy.height() < this.textarea.height())) {
    this.textarea.animate({height: (this.dummy.height() + this.line_height) + 'px'}, 100); 
}
}
} 
}
}); 
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I've been using this plugin for some time with no problems.  Can you post an demo online so we can test? Also is this happening in all browsers? 

Interesting aside: the [autogrow][1] plugin website comes up as an attack site now in firefox! It's not of course.

[1]: http://www.aclevercookie.com/demos/autogrow_textarea.html

Comment: @jeerose, I'm using the plugin on a blank page that I created just to test it, so it's the only script running + jquery 1.3.2. I wish I had a live server to test on the moment, but nothing that I can post on the forum here :(

Comment: It seems that others have reported a similar behavior before, but for IE. I'm not sure why it's happening to me in both FF and IE. It's not related to the functionality of the plugin itself, but I'm guessing something that has to do with calculating the height or something similar.

Comment: Chris, go here (http://www.pspt.ca/connect/pastorsblog) and toggle the comments for one of the blog posts.  The textarea for your blog comment uses this plugin (a site I built). Does it jitter for you here?

Comment: Hey jeerose, I went there and toggled the comments with no problems, very smooth :) do you have something in mind as to the reason why?

Comment: Not without seeing what you're doing.  My initial thought is for you to grab the exact js files and css that I'm using with regard to that comment box and try it locally. Let me know what results you end up with (maybe there's a problem with your plugin file or more likely, your css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regard to jeerose's comment:

> http://www.aclevercookie.com/aclevercookiecom-breached-problem-resolved/
>
> It has been brought to my attention by
>   visitors that their virus protection
>   goes off when they come to this blog. 
>   I investigated the matter and found
>   that harmful code had been injected
>   into the source of the site.
>
> This has been resolved and measures
>   have been taken to increase the
>   security of the site.
>
> Thanks for the report, and I apologize
>   for the alarm.

Which doesn't seem to be true. As my antivirus still fires when opening that site

Comment: Yeah I know but was too long to fit into comment field. And this way more people read it and don't go onto this site unti he really clears the problem